# Can torch.where() used in a equivalent broadcsating form?

Tags: numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I have the following segment of for loop in my code. The nested loop is slowing down my complete execution.

```
for q in range(batchSize):
    temp=torch.where((composition_matrix == pred[q]).all(dim=1))[0]
    if len(temp)==0:
        output[q]=0
    else:
        output[q]=int(temp[0])
```

Here, `composition_matrix` is `[14000,2]` dimensional pytorch tensor with only positive integers as cell values. `pred` and `output` both are a `[batchSize,2]` dimensional torch tensor.
As this for loop is slowing my code a lot and I am unable to get the equivalent broadcasting solution to this code segment.

Does a broadcasting solution exists to eleminate this for loop?

I shall be grateful for any help.

A minimum reproducible example is

```
import torch
composition_matrix=torch.randint(3, 10, (14000,2))
batchSize=64
pred=torch.randint(3, 10, (batchSize,2))
output=torch.zeros([batchSize])

for q in range(batchSize):
    temp=torch.where((composition_matrix == pred[q]).all(dim=1))[0]
    if len(temp)==0:
        output[q]=0
    else:
        output[q]=int(temp[0])
```

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @yannziselman I have edited the question to add a working example.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. If you would, please add a **minimal** reproducible example that includes both **deterministic** inputs and the outputs you **expect** to get  for those inputs and can be easily read in the qustion as **clearly explained in the link** i posted in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simple, you first need to understand what the operation is essentially doing. You've got two tensors. Tensor A is of shape `(14000, 2)` and tensor B is of shape `(64, 2)`. The operation you want to do is:

> For each row B[i] in B, compare that B[i] (of shape (2,) with A (of
> shape (14000, 2)). If B[i] occurs within A, set output[i] = index of
> first occurrence.

This can actually be done in two lines of code (maybe even one line):

```
comp = (composition_matrix[:, None, :] == pred).all(dim=-1)
output = torch.argmax(comp.float(), axis=0)
```

- The first line creates `comp`, the broadcasted comparison of `composition_matrix` and `pred`, a boolean tensor of shape `(14000, 64)`.
- The second line needs to find the "index of the first match". This can be done quite simply with argmax: it will return the index of the first "1" (or if all the values are "0", will return the first index, ie, 0).

(Note that torch does not support argmax for "bool" tensors, and so comp needed to be cast to another data type.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mercury. This is an simple yet efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the short and probably over-simplified example. I fear a bigger one would be much more difficult to visualize. But I hope this suits your purpose.
My solution may seem a little complicated but it's fully vectorized and includes no explicit loops.
Here's what I would do:

```
import torch

torch.manual_seed(0)
batchSize = 8

pred               = torch.randint(0, 10, (batchSize, 2))
output             = torch.zeros((batchSize, 2))
composition_matrix = torch.randint(0, 10, (14, 2))

# compair all vectors in composition_matrix to all vectors in pred
comparisons = (composition_matrix.unsqueeze(0) == pred.unsqueeze(1))
comparisons = comparisons.all(2)

# form an index array the shape of the comparisons array
comparison_idxs = torch.arange(comparisons.shape[1])
comparison_idxs = comparison_idxs.repeat(batchSize).reshape(*comparisons.shape)

# multipy the comparisons array by the index array 
where_result = (comparison_idxs*comparisons)

# replace invalind zeros with the maximal value in each sample
batch_idxs   = torch.arange(comparisons.shape[0])
batch_idxs   = batch_idxs.repeat(comparisons.shape[1])
batch_idxs   = batch_idxs.reshape(comparisons.shape[1], comparisons.shape[0]).T
maxima       = where_result.max(1).values[batch_idxs]
maxima_vecor = maxima[(1-comparisons.int()).bool()]
where_result[(1-comparisons.int()).bool()] = maxima_vecor

vectorized_output = where_result.min(1)[0]

output = torch.zeros([batchSize])
for q in range(batchSize):
    temp=torch.where((composition_matrix == pred[q]).all(dim=1))[0]
    if len(temp)==0:
        output[q]=0
    else:
        output[q]=int(temp[0])
```

output:

```
composition_matrix = 
tensor([[6, 8],
        [4, 3],
        [6, 9],
        [1, 4],
        [4, 1],
        [9, 9],
        [9, 0],
        [1, 2],
        [3, 0],
        [5, 5],
        [2, 9],
        [1, 8],
        [8, 3],
        [6, 9]])
pred = 
tensor([[4, 9],
        [3, 0],
        [3, 9],
        [7, 3],
        [7, 3],
        [1, 6],
        [6, 9],
        [8, 6]])
output = 
tensor([0., 8., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0.])
vectorized_output = 
tensor([0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0])
```

Some timing results:

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
batchSize = 8
pred               = torch.randint(0, 10, (batchSize, 2))
composition_matrix = torch.randint(0, 10, (14000, 2))


print('timing the vectorized_solution:')
%timeit -n 1000 vectorized_solution(composition_matrix, pred,)

print('timing the loop_solution:')
%timeit -n 1000 loop_solution(composition_matrix, pred,)
```

output:

```
timing the vectorized_solution:
1000 loops, best of 5: 137 µs per loop
timing the loop_solution:
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @yann-zisheman. You solution too works fine.